# Не получается динамически скрывать layout

Tags: android, xml, разметка

Делаю командную игру, команд может быть от 2 до 4.
Сделал активити для выбора аватарок играющих команд.
Сделал xml с четырьмя превьюшками.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать так, чтоб если играют всего три команды, то четвертую превьюшку прятать, а оставшиеся разместить равномерно по горизонтали. То же самое для двух команд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если ставлю у лайоута `layout_width="0px"`, то картинка полностью не исчезает. Пробовал всякие варианты, так ничего и не добился. Как сделать требуемое попроще?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llTeamPreview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/TeamPreview1"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="#CDDC39"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llTeamPreview2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="2" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/TeamPreview2"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="#CDDC39"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llTeamPreview3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="3" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/TeamPreview3"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="#CDDC39"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llTeamPreview4"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="4" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/TeamPreview4"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#CDDC39" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: view.setVisibility( View.Gone );

Comment: То что надо, спасибо